# SQL Server LicenseType is disbled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Enterprise and applied the license key but

```
SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType') is disbaled and  
SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses') is null
```

There is no key in the registery such as following for SQL Server 2016:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\Setup

Any idea how can I change LicenseType of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how can I change LicenseType of SQL Server?

Since licenses are assigned to servers externally, you can switch which licenses are assigned to which servers any time you want, subject to the restrictions on License Mobility, documented in the [SQL Server Licensing Guide](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/8/C/78CDF005-97C1-4129-926B-CE4A6FE92CF5/SQL_Server_2017_Licensing_guide.pdf).  Basically you can only move licenses once every 90 days unless you have [Software Assurance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/software-assurance-default.aspx), or experience a disaster.

Answer (score 6):

If you read official documentation of [Serverproperty (T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it says

> L**icenseType:**   Unused. License information is not preserved or maintained by the SQL Server product. Always returns DISABLED.
>
> **NumLicenses**: Unused. License information is not preserved or maintained by the SQL Server product. Always returns NULL.

SQL Server does not stores license information anywhere inside its mostly on paper or in some kind of agreement between you and Microsoft or you and Vendor who is providing the software copy. Having said that you can get very limited information when you run `select @@version`

> Any idea how can I change LicenseType of SQL Server?

You simply cannot unless you buy a totally different license.

PS:Dont worry your SQL Server installation is fine